# Jump to a string in a PDF document

Tags: pdf-tools

I want to write a function that jumps to a given string in a pdf document. I am using `pdf-tools`. Naively, I thought this would work:

```lisp
(defun goto-string-in-pdf (pdffile)
  "Jump to string 999 in pdffile"
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window pdffile)))
    (with-selected-window win 
      (pdf-view-goto-page 1)
      (search-forward "999"))))
```

But it seems `search-forward` doesn't work in PDFView-mode. So how do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from choosing the right buffer, this function suggests the necessary steps.

```
(defun pdf-search-forward (string)
  (interactive "sString: ")
  ;; Expect a pdf-window, else the highlighting won't work.
  (pdf-util-assert-pdf-window)
  ;; Get a list of matches, discarding all but the first.
  (let-alist (car (pdf-info-search-string
                   "Number"
                   (cons (pdf-view-current-page) 0)))
    (unless .page
      (error "Not found: %s" string))
    (pdf-view-goto-page .page)
    ;; Scale the edges of the match according to the displayed
    ;; page-size.
    (let ((pixel-edges
           (pdf-util-scale-relative-to-pixel .edges))
          (pdf-isearch-batch-mode t))
      ;; Highlight and focus the match.
      (pdf-isearch-hl-matches pixel-edges nil t)
      (pdf-isearch-focus-match-batch pixel-edges))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. From your code I derived that `(pdf-view-goto-page (alist-get 'page (car (pdf-info-search-string myString))))` solves my problem, that is, jumps to the page in the pdf with the first occurence of myString.